# Jquery Click <li> dropdown option

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code from WHMCS Client Area Dashboard.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#"><span data-value="all">All Entries</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span data-value="Terminated">Terminated</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span data-value="Cancelled">Cancelled</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span data-value="Active">Active</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to click "Active" option by default.

After several tries, I figured out below code can work for me

```
$('.dropdown-menu li:nth-child(4) a').click();
```

But the issue is, Active tab is not fixed at 4th position.

Want to change the below code so it actually use "Active" value instead of 4th option.

```
$('.dropdown-menu li:nth-child(4) a').click();
```

I am learning Jquery, already tried searching many threads. Couldn't find one. Need help.

Comment: Is there any more code involved? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: Use `.filter()` with `.data()`

Comment: can you clarify bit more? @AnuragSrivastava

Comment: Yes, @NicoHaase i have tried many times but could not get the solution. help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use data attribute for selector `$('.dropdown-menu span[data-value="Active"]')`.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I am getting error - https://prnt.sc/snb7eg

Comment: @YellowJacketSting I think you did not add the event itself to my selector `$('.dropdown-menu span[data-value="Active"]').click()`. Note that the event is triggered specifically on `span`, and not on `a`.